# Displaying host and database names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display the current host and database names in a view.

Where can I get these names?

Are there some predefined environment or global variables?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a rails configuration object and obtain the necessary information from it:

```
config   = Rails::Configuration.new
host     = config.database_configuration[RAILS_ENV]["host"]
database = config.database_configuration[RAILS_ENV]["database"]
```

See the [documentation](http://edgedocs.planetargon.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html) for Rails::Configuration for details.

Comment: Documentation link is broken. Is it supposed to point to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html ?

Answer (score 76):

With Rails 3 you can use

```
Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

or

```
Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

or

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
```

Comment: You got it for `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` I think that is the cleanest way of doing it.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` worked for finding all configurations rather than `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` for the current config.

Comment: nice one, I like ```ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config```

Comment: This should go without saying, but keep in mind this will also include the credentials in plain text for most set ups.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config` in Rails 7

Answer (score 27):

The Rails::configuration.new answer does not work in Rails 3

```
config   = Rails::Configuration.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Rails::Configuration:Module
[...]
```

If you are using MySQL or Postgres then this works

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

But this only works with drivers that have implemented that method. For example, it will not work for SQLite.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database also works for postgres, the driver is abstracted away so guessing it works for all databases

Comment: @house9 I edited the answer to reflect this, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

On Rails 3, this is most easily accessed via `Rails::Application.config`, like so:

```
    YourApplicationClassName::Application.config.database_configuration[::Rails.env]
```

If you try to call it directly on `Rails` instead of `YourApplicationClassName`, rails will give you a deperecation warning. If you don't know what your application constant is, try `Rails.application.class.name` in a Rails console for your app.

Comment: Works in Rails 4 as well. Not sure what Pavel is referring to.

Answer (score 9):

The method below is nice when you are connected to multiple databases. Tested on Sqlite3 and Mysql2

```
MyModel.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)[:database]
```

Comment: When using multiple databases this is the answer you need

Answer (score 8):

Tested in Rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)
```

next info should be out:
adapter, host, encoding, reconnect, database name, username, pass

Answer (score 1):

Just this should work
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.database_name`

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, that database configuration is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config` in Rails 7.

To get the name you can do `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.database`